# Boostrap Nav Bar toggle button not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I recently set up my bootstrap navbar but when I go down to moblie size and click the expand button it does nothing. Any ideas on why this is? I used to make this navbar with bootstrap 4 maybe I have the wrong classes for boostrap 5.

```
  <nav class="navpaddingy navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img class="navimage" src="images/logo.png" alt=""></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto navpaddingx">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Ceramic Coatings</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Exterior Wash</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link disabled">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

check out the docs for more info :] https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navbar/